# How to return error string from json object without the first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

This is my json object

```
                {"result":0,
                  "last-name":'please enter your last name',
                  "quantity":'quantity must be a number',
                  "email": 'please enter a valid email '}
```

I need the element "result":0, because it lets me know there is an error, so that I can then pass it to an error string.

However I need to remove the 0 from the error output string because the end user only needs the error messages when they are outputted. 
I have tried to change the object to an array and also tried few array methods such as pop() and slice() but I am having trouble putting them into action. I think I may need to loop through the array but this seems over kill as I know that I only want to remove the 'result' element which is always at the start.

This is how I am returning the error array:

```
 var errorString = '<div class="alert alert-danger">';

            errorString  +=    '<table >';
            for( key in o) {
            errorString +=   '<tr>';
            errorString  +=   '<td>';

            errorString +=  o[key]  ;
            errorString +=   '</tr>';
            // alert( " " + [ key ] + ", " + o[ key ] );
            }
            errorString += '</table>' ;
            errorString += '</div>' ;

            $(".info").append(errorString);


                    $(function() {
                            $('.info').delay(1000).fadeOut('.info', function() {
                            $('.info').empty();
                            $('.info').show();
                                                                              });
                                  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var jsonObj = {"result":0,
              "last-name":'please enter your last name',
              "quantity":'quantity must be a number',
              "email": 'please enter a valid email '};
delete jsonObj.result;
// or
delete jsonObj['result'];
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/kELML/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use [**delete**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) to remove the property from your JSON object, then pass it to your error handling method

```
var yourJSONObj=JSON.parse(yourJsonString);

delete yourJSONObj.result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var obj = {"result":0,
              "last-name":'please enter your last name',
              "quantity":'quantity must be a number',
              "email": 'please enter a valid email '}


obj.result returns the "result" key only

delete obj.result will return the object without the result key
```

Then you can iterate or do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Which uses jQuery **[$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)** method

```
var o = {
"result":0,
"last-name":'please enter your last name',
"quantity":'quantity must be a number',
"email": 'please enter a valid email '};

var errorString  = '<table >';
$.each(o, function(i, key){

    if(i != "result")// check for result
    {
        errorString += '<tr>';
        errorString  += '<td>';
        alert(key);
        errorString += key  ;
        errorString  +='</td>';
        errorString +='</tr>';
    }
});
errorString += '</table>';
```

Here is the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7PhAB/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string, then do a `JSON.parse` to convert to a json object. Otherwise first check if there is an error, if yes then iterate the object after deleting the first property.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/NE5v5/***

Example Code:

```
var s = '{"result":0, "last-name":"please enter your last name", "quantity":"quantity must be a number", "email":"please enter a valid email"}' ;

var j = JSON.parse(s); // If a string, first make a json object

if (! j.result) { // check if there is an error, 0 means false
    delete j.result; // if there is an error, delete the first property
    for(var key in j) { // iterate the object properties
        // key  contains the property name
        // j[key]  contains the property value
    }
}
```